# What is Insertion Sort?

Tags: c#, sorting, insertion-sort

I am new to programming and just heard about sorting. I went through the basics of sorting and found out that Insertion Sorting is the easiest. But the thing is that I don't get what it is! Can you explain me in detail what is insertion sort and how to implement it. Implementation in c# would be appreciated more.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)**

Comment: have you looked at wikipedia?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort Wikipedia already has a detailed explaination. Anything you don't understand? please point it out.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not Google. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Comment: but I asked the question about programming! isn't it related to it?

Comment: A quick search in Google would find MANY references and probably a ton of example code on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a loot at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertionsort)

The algorithm for insertion-sort is

```
 int temp, j;

 for (int i=1; i < vector.length; i++){
   temp = vector[i];
   j = i-1;

   while (j >= 0 && vector[j] > temp){
     vector[j + 1] = vector[j];
     j--;
   }

   vector[j+1] = temp;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Insertion sort is more efficient than the alogrithms we have implemented before (Bubble Sort and Selection sort) for sorting a small data set. Insertion sort is mostly used when the list is partially sorted. We assume the 1st element is sorted. Then we check adjacent index for smaller or greater value. If the value is smaller, we insert it in the left side of index[0] which means now smaller value is at index[0] and if it's greater than the  original value of index[0] then we get a sorted list of 2 elements. We implement same approach to adjacent elements. Then compare it to previous elements to create a sorted list. So basically - you'll end up with sorted list on the left side of the array and unsorted on the right at one stage. Remember we go back and check if the array is sorted - we do not go forward unless the array behind the concerned element (incl. concerned element) is completely sorted.

Here's the C# implementation of Insertion Sort:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i, j;
            int[] unsortedarrayed = new int[] { 34, 36, 2, 7, 8, 3, 6, 5 };

            for (i = 0; i < unsortedarrayed.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(unsortedarrayed[i]);
            }

            int[] sortedarray = InsertionSorted(unsortedarrayed);

            for (i = 0; i < sortedarray.Length; i++)    
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sortedarray[i]);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }

        public static int[] InsertionSorted(int[] unsortedarrayed)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < unsortedarrayed.Length; i++)
            {
                int temp = unsortedarrayed[i];
                int j = i - 1;

                while ((j > -1) && (unsortedarrayed[j] > temp))
                {
                    int tempo = unsortedarrayed[j + 1];
                    unsortedarrayed[j + 1] = unsortedarrayed[j];
                    unsortedarrayed[j] = tempo;

                    j = j - 1;
                }
            }

            return unsortedarrayed;
        }
    }
```

Source :
  For more detail click on following  links :
   1) [Link 1](http://weemundo.com/insertion-sort-c)
   2) [Link 2](http://www.softwareandfinance.com/CSharp/Insertion_Sort.html)

Comment: well, could you at least format the code and remove redundant statements?

Comment: that code is not working properly!